# MySQL: Dropping table with specific table prefix from the Database using Terminal

Tags: mysql, drop-table

I am trying to delete database tables from PhpMyAdmin using a Terminal (Guake Terminal) with a specific table prefix. I am trying to delete tables with the prefix **wordpress2_** at the beginning of it.

These are the format of the codes I used but it seems like it is not working. Could you possibly help me with this?

```
mysql -B DatabaseName -u DatabaseUser -pDatabasePassword -e "SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ';') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'wordpress2_%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName';"
```

Thank you very much and your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a `SELECT` to create the SQL statements such as `DROP`.  But you cannot directly execute the generated SQL.

A better way is to create a Stored Procedure that does the select into string(s), then uses `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` to actually perform the SQL.  (Of course, then use `CALL` to invoke the SP, passing parameters if suitable.)

Comment: Hi, Thank you. It seems a little bit complicated and I am still learning. Would it be possible to ask for a sample code based on the code snippet I have provided? Thank you very much

Comment: There are several on stackoverflow.com; search in it for `[mysql] information_schema`.  Here's one I did for something more complex: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot